# Interrupted bulk insert statement while on table lock

Tags: mysql, locking

In a production server we've got a huge Myisam table that collects visits and we run a routine once a month let's say to move old data to an Archive table and make the huge table lighter for backups etc. The problem is when in the process of running the routine if the server crashes or simply mysql had to restart it may interrupt the insert to archive statement or the delete from live table statement. As we cannot use transactions because of the ARCHIVE engine for the archive table, is locking the tables a solution ? or have we to plan integrity checks manually ?

Comment: Locking table will only guarantee that your data wouldn't be changed by external processes during your operation. It will not save you in case of crash-in-the-middle and so you'll have to plan integrity checks & restoring (because there will be no transaction `ROLLBACK` available - I recommend to insert first, then check integrity, then, if all is well, delete records, then check if deletion was ok)

Comment: Thanks very much @AlmaDo, it's gonna be some painful work to do/debug, I cant even think of tests as we are in the DB.